# Why = instead of - in selector results selects all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have encountered a very strange behavior using jQuery. I have a `function` like this:

```
            function refreshTechBubble(techID, value) {
                $("span.top-right-data[data-id=" + techID + "]").html(value);
            }
```

This `function` refreshes a specific technician bubble. To make it more simple and technical, let's just state that this function changes the inner html of a `span` uniquely found via the selector of `"span.top-right-data[data-id=" + techID + "]"`. This is all very nice and everything works properly.

However, while implementing this, I made a typo and I had this incorrect implementation:

```
            function refreshTechBubble(techID, value) {
                $("span.top-right-data[data=id=" + techID + "]").html(value);
            }
```

Notice, that I have written **=** instead of **-** by accident. While the fix was trivial and I do not have any problems to solve in this moment, I still wonder about the cause of the behavior I experienced during testing. With such a typo I would expect jQuery to not find any tags and consequently to not refresh their inner html, however, instead it refreshed the inner HTML of all the `span`s having a `class` of `top-right-data`. Why did I experience this behavior before the fix instead of the behavior I expected?

Comment: You'll want to report it as a bug. My guess is that they simply ignore invalid selectors.

Comment: I get a syntax error right away.

Comment: BUT thats a `feature` my friend ;)

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: I get `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: span.top-right-data[data=id=1]` as expected

Comment: Unable to reproduce the behaviour you describe - I get an error: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: span.top-right-data[data=id=a]` https://jsfiddle.net/jh7jdaf1/

Comment: Like the others above, I get a nice clear exception too. Went all the way back to jQuery v1.9.1 on Chrome, Firefox, and IE: https://jsfiddle.net/rbLzjj8g/1/ (in case jQuery is handing the parsing off to the browser's built-in engine, as it doesn't contain any jQuery-specific enhancements).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, guys. I am using jQuery 1.7.1 (unfortunately) since this is an old project with lots of client-side stuff and time was not allocated to refresh jQuery's version yet. As far as I understand, the behavior in newer jQuery instances was to throw a syntax error. That would have not surprised me either. However, unfortunately I did not observe my error, since in my test case I had a single technician and I have observed the problem live, which made the fix very urgent. I was wondering about the cause of the behavior.

Comment: Based on the feedbacks I have received in the comment section, it seems that newer jQuery versions will consider this to be a syntax error, therefore the behavior I experienced seems to be a deprecated behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in the old version of Sizzle that was part of jQuery up to and including 1.7. It was fixed in the Sizzle rewrite in 1.8 (though it's not listed among the bugs that were fixed in the [release notes](https://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released)).

Interestingly, all versions of jQuery seem to correctly throw a SYNTAX_ERR when the attribute selector either appears alone or is qualified by an explicit universal selector. It's only when the attribute selector is qualified by any other simple selector (appearing either before or after it) that it doesn't cause a SYNTAX_ERR.